# Polymer update route from custom element

Tags: polymer

Complete Polyer noob here trying to write a simple little Polymer app.

What I'm trying to do is drive navigation of my iron-pages from a custom element (client-table) but can not figure out how to do this.

I've tried various permutations of using attr-for-selected and selected attributes within the table, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried setting up an anchor tag around the paper-button, and almost got that working, but it would trigger a full page refresh and not display my #clientInfo section when the page loaded.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this, links to documentation that better explain routing/navigation in Polymer (esp. in cases of using custom elements), any default Polymer elements I should inspect the source of, etc?

```
<!-- snippet from index.html -->
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
    <section data-route="home">
      <paper-material elevation="1">
        <h2>Clients</h2>
        <client-table></client-table>
           <a data-route="clientInfo" href="/">test</a>
      </paper-material>
    </section>

    <section data-route="clientInfo">
      <paper-material elevation="1">
        <h2></h2>
        <p>This is the users section</p>
        <a href="/users/Rob">Rob</a>
      </paper-material>
    </section>
</iron-pages>

<!-- snipped from client-table.html -->
buildTable: function() {
    var domTable = this.$.table;
    var tableData = this.parseTableJson(this.buildTableJson());
    var tableMarkup = this.buildTable_initTable() + "<tbody>";

    for (var index in tableData) {
        row = tableData[index];

        var rowMarkup = "<tr>";
        rowMarkup += "<td>" + row.clientFirstName + "</td>";
        rowMarkup += "<td>" + row.clientLastName + "</td>";
        rowMarkup += "<td>" + row.clientEmail + "</td>";
        rowMarkup += "<td>" + row.clientPhone  + "</td>";
        rowMarkup += "<td>" + row.clientZipCode  + "</td>";
        rowMarkup += "<td><paper-button><iron-icon icon='card-membership'></iron-icon></paper-button></td>";
        rowMarkup += "</tr>";

        tableMarkup += rowMarkup;
    }
    tableMarkup += "</tbody>";

    $(domTable).append(tableMarkup);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

And then I found `routing.html`.

Comment: So in addition to discoreving that the Polymer Starter Kit (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) uses Page.js (https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) and correctly configuring routes through Page.js this Stackoverflow post helped me over the final hurdle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685807/polymer-1-0-iron-pages-not-switching-pages-with-children-event  

Also, looking at the source to iron-pages and iron-selectable-behavior helped.